# Global access log and vhost access logs?

Tags: apache-2.2, logging

I am running Apache2 with Froxlor, so every customer gets their own access and error log in `/var/customers/logs`.

Now, is it possible to keep this functionality while also having a global access and error log the good old `/var/log` way that contains all traffic and errors?

I have tried defining a `CustomLog` in the global `apache2.conf` to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to add another `CustomLog` line to every vhost. Each pointing to the very same file.

Setting this up is a little bit of effort since you may have to edit a lot of vhost configurations but afterwards it works like a charm.

Example lines for a `<VirtualHost ...>` segment:

```
CustomLog /var/www/web0123/access.log combined
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log vhost_combined
```

`APACHE_LOG_DIR` is optional and may be defined in the `envvars` configuration file.